# Object Child Key Path

Tags: javascript, object

I want to iterate through nested Object and I want to store the all the child keys path as separate array

```
{
    "A": {
        "C": {
            "G": {}
        }
    },
    "B": {
        "D": {
            "G": {}
        },
        "E": {
            "H": {}
        },
        "F": {
            "I": {
                "H": {}
            },
            "J": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I need Array in below format.

A,C,G
B,D,G
B,E,H
B,F,J
B,F,I,H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with `Object.entries` to get the values.

Here is an example.

```js
const data = {
    "A": {
        "C": {
            "G": {}
        }
    },
    "B": {
        "D": {
            "G": {}
        },
        "E": {
            "H": {}
        },
        "F": {
            "I": {
                "H": {}
            },
            "J": {}
        }
    }
};

const result = []

function getPaths(data,path=''){
  const list = Object.entries(data)
  if(!list.length){
    result.push(path)
    return
  }
  
  list.forEach(([key,value])=>getPaths(value,path ? path+','+key : key))
}

getPaths(data)

console.log(result)
```